# Is the Mirage Tower in ORAS?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

The [Mirage Tower](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mirage_Tower) was a feature that was unique to Pokémon Emerald and I thought that maybe the devs would put it in ORAS, but so far, I haven't been finding it in the remakes. I did some quick searches and they all seem to lead to the conclusion that the Mirage Tower won't be in ORAS, and one of the reasons was that there was an NPC in BW (or some other version) who mentioned that it won't reappear. Thing now is that BW's timeline is supposed to be after that of RSE, so there still might be a possibility of it being there.

Another thing that might conclude why it won't be there would be that it never was in Ruby or Sapphire in the first place, but in Emerald, so the odds of it being in ORAS again falls pretty low.

So I guess my question really is, has anyone been able to see the Mirage Tower? I personally spent 20 minutes going in and out of the desert and looking for it at its usual spot. Or maybe there is some trick (kind of like the method to unlock the Regi-Pokémon) to be able to see it first and if so, does anyone know the requirements?

Comment: I don't think there is Mirage Tower in ORAS, but Root/Claw fossils are available on route 111, in the desert.

Comment: I guess not :( If anyone can put an answer, I will accept it even if it says Mirage Tower wasn't implemented, but it should be properly backed up as far as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need it? The fossils are available in the desert, as well as Sandshrew and Trapinch. From googling around, I don't see any other reason why Mirage Tower is good for anything. I also can't seem to find any at least semi-official confirmation that it's in the game, although there are multiple forum posts about it.

Comment: @Chippies Well, tbh, it wasn't about the usefulness of it, but rather whether it was or wasn't in. Thing is that this was one of the things that stood out from this particular generation of Pokemon games and I was kind of hoping to see it redone better, and maybe some harder challenges too. Kind of like the trick house (which fortunately is still there). Lots of not so useful items there, and others the devs could easily have put somewhere else in game, but it exists solely for being a little challenge.

Comment: Well considering that Pokemon Delta Emerald was trademarked, I would bet that the Mirage Tower will come back in the proper remake.

Comment: @Thebluefish Could be, but I somehow doubt it... the devs have never remade a version that was a mix of two previous ones, like Yellow, Crystal. I feel more like they trademarked it so that other people wouldn't make a Delta Emerald and the public thus associating the game with the official ones.

Comment: Notice that according to [PokeBeach](http://pokebeach.com/2014/05/delta-emerald-trademark-registered-by-pokemon), "[t]he chances of this being a new Pokemon game are unlikely based on past company practices, as Pokemon usually registers multiple game titles every generation. Among many others, “Pokemon Gray” was registered during Generation V and “Pokemon WaterBlue” was also registered in Generation III. But no core Pokemon titles have ever been discovered early through trademarks. It seems Pokemon just registers multiple titles to cover their bases."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mirage tower is definitely **not present in ORAS**. The fossils are just laying on the sand in the desert on route 111. An observation that points to this fact.

Also from [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mirage_Tower) -

> A Backpacker in Pokémon Black and White 2 makes reference to the
>   tower, saying, "The Mirage Tower in a desert of the Hoenn region has
>   disappeared."

Comment: Isn't the Black & White 2 reference more likely to be a reference to how it disappeared after the player left in the events of RS?